# How to fix 'ids is not a function' error in javascript

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

my eventual goal is to use the array data in chartist.js to create a dashboard.  I am a beginner in javascript and to programming, I do understand that I need to add variables yet for the chart.  My first goal is to add more console.log to see the arrays before moving forward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>first chart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart" class="ct-golden-section"></div> 
<script>

fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxY1tXSC6zbwvRc330EfyBNKgE0YiLWXx6p868uJh2d/dev')

    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    //.then(data => console.log(data))
//declare the data variable   
    var data = {
      //set our labels (x-axis) to the Label values from the JSON data
      labels: ids.map(function(id) {
        return id.Date;
      }),
      //set our values to Value value from the JSON data
      series: ids.map(function(id) {
        return id.Weight;
      })
    };

</script>

</body>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a moment to read through [how to actually format a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and then edit yours so that code shows up as code. Right now half your question is missing because you decided to text-quote it instead. (Related to that, make sure to read through the [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) policy article as well, because you're asking real people for help, so help them be able to help you)

Comment: `ids` is not a function because you don't define the array anywhere (at least I am not seeing it)

Comment: What is your variable `ids` referring to?

Comment: thanks mike...i did go through how to ask a question and followed it.  im really struggling here because I have no idea what Im doing (javascript) so its hard to ask any thing but my current problem

Comment: maybe that is my issue that im not using .map() properly?  Im trying to adapt my json file from this example https://medium.com/@michaelmangial1/csv-to-json-to-chartist-js-7c5c9e2c37c4.  I thought that ids referred to the name of the json file.  I guess not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon looking at the JSON data sent back, i found that you were trying to access the data incorrectly (using map). Instead you want to directly access each array inside it's structure (Being: weight > Date, weight > Weight). Sometimes you need to analyze the objects you are receiving to retrieve the correct data

Secondly, after look at the link you posted in the comments, it looks as if you have missed a key piece of code `.then(function(ids))`. The full function is shown below:

```
fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxY1tXSC6zbwvRc330EfyBNKgE0YiLWXx6p868uJh2d/dev')

    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(ids) {  //Code that is required
        var data = {
            //set our labels (x-axis) to the Label values from the JSON data
            labels: ids.weight.Date,        //Retrieve relevant array
            //set our values to Value value from the JSON data
            series: ids.weight.Weight       //Retrieve relevant array
    }
  });
```

When it calls `.then(function(ids))`, it is waiting for the previous statement to execute, and then passing the return value of the previous call as the variable ids. In your code, ids was never defined.

Comment: Thanks.  That's makes more sense.  I would like to understand why I can't use my data in the attached link or how to send data to the console log for verification....I voted up

Comment: If you want to see what each value is in the console, simply just do `console.log(ids.weight.Date);` or `console.log(ids.weight.Weight);` just before you set the `data` variable

Comment: I will try that.... Thanks again...this has really helped me move forward